# How can I call android functions in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new in Vue.js, so I want to know if I can call android functions in Vue.js. On my android side, I made this `myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android")` and then in Vue js I want to call
 `Android.someFunction()`. Is that possbile?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can use 'Android.function()' it will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
WebView webView = (WebView);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:app.$children[0].$children[0].updateBookmarkedList("+ new JSONArray(svcids) +")");
```

Like this

```
// js

window.app = new Vue(

)
```

Comment: Please add some description along with code snippet. It will help users to precisely understand code